# Automated Reports from Azure to show Pricing Tier of all SQL DBs

Tags: azure

Is there anyway I can get an scheduled report from Azure to show all the SQL Databases we look after that are above a certain Pricing Tier?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use budgets:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/tutorial-acm-create-budgets

This object will track current spending on your resources then you can add alert rule which will trigger proper action when criteria defined by you will be meet.